# The type arguments for method 'CommandService.AddModuleAsync<T>(IServiceProvider)' cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: c#, bots, discord

I'm trying to make a bot with this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=egq26JwyJkc (11:47) and with the same code I'm getting this error

```
The type arguments for method 'CommandService.AddModuleAsync<T>(IServiceProvider)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

Even with programming knowledge it's hard to understand what is going on here...

This is my code

```
using Discord.Commands;
using Discord.WebSocket;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace forTesting
{
    public class CommandHandler
    {
        private DiscordSocketClient _client;

        private CommandService _service;

        public CommandHandler(DiscordSocketClient client)
        {
            _client = client;

            _service = new CommandService();

            _service.AddModuleAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing a letter **s** in method name AddModule**s**Async

Comment: Now I'm getting: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'services' of 'CommandService.AddModulesAsync(Assembly, IServiceProvider)'

Comment: I added second argument "null" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This means you need to specify what T is.

Try specifying T based on the generic method limitations.

Comment: you typed my code back, how do I specify T based on the generic method limitations? and why the guys in the video didn't have to do that?

Comment: I havent watched your video. Look at what T should be; then look at your code to see which one is type(T), the specify it; maybe _service.AddModuleAsync<CommandService>(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()), if CommandService is T

Comment: how do I know which one is T? I gave you the full code

Comment: your code gave me "cannot convert from 'System.Reflection.Assembly' to 'System.IServiceProvider'"

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017, I think F12 or F11 should tell you!

Comment: Not working, pressing F12 does nothing or it says "Cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret".

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party but hopefully someone may find this information helpful with regards to the above issue. After an update modules are built when added to the CommandService, as well as on command execution. As such, an IServiceProvider is now required for the building phase of modules.

So the answer you are looking for is:

`await Commands.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), _service);`

Answer (score 0):

Pass null for the IServiceProvider.

_service.AddModuleAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()**, null**);